# array_search Recursive in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, logic, business-logic

```
function array_searchRecursive( $needle, $haystack, $strict=false, $path=array() )
{
    if( !is_array($haystack) ) {
        return false;
    }

    foreach( $haystack as $key => $val ) {

        if( is_array($val) && $subPath = array_searchRecursive($needle, $val, $strict, $path) ) {
            $path = array_merge($path, array($key), $subPath);

            return $path;
        } else if( (!$strict && $val == $needle) || ($strict && $val === $needle) ) {

            $path[] = $key;
            return $path;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Do any body suggest me the same funcitonality, that can be implemented in javascript.
reference http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php#68424

Comment: The super awesome [PHP.js](http://phpjs.org/) project has a function that may be a good starting point for you: http://phpjs.org/functions/array_search/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might give you a start. Not thoroughly tested or highly optimized, and assumes use of jQuery (shouldn't be a big problem to replace the jQuery utilty functions with other implementations).

```
function searchArrayRecursive(needle, haystack, strict) {

    function constructPath(needle, haystack, path, strict) {
        if (!$.isArray(haystack)) {
            return false;
        }
        var index;
        for (index = 0; index < haystack.length; index++) {
            var value = haystack[index];
            var currentPath = $.merge([], path);
            currentPath.push(index);

            if ((strict && value === needle) || (!strict && value == needle)) {
                return currentPath;
            }
            if ($.isArray(value)) {

                var foundPath = constructPath(needle, value, currentPath, strict);
                if (foundPath) {
                    return foundPath;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }


    return constructPath(needle, haystack, [], strict);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b8TxJ/2/

Comment: to expand upon @Amitay's work, here is a function to return the path when haystack contains array(s) and/or object(s): http://jsfiddle.net/jshado1/rKHXC/

Answer (score 1):

Indeed underscore (or probably better performing: lodash) is your man.
JavaScript is for a huge part a functional language and in the latest spec contains most features that underscore provides. For browser-compat underscore is still adviced.

The best underscore feature in your situation is:

```
var haystack = [
  {a: 1}, [{b: 2}, {c: 3}, [{d: 4}, {e: 5}, [{f: 6}, {g: 7}] ] ]
],
needle = 4;

//Search
var result = _(haystack).chain() //chain so we can keep underscoring
  .flatten() //flatten the array
  .find(function(o) { //find the first element that matches our search function
    return _(o).chain() //chain so we can keep underscoring
      .values() //get all object values as an array
      .contains(needle) //see if any of our values contains the needle
      .value(); //get out of the chain
  })
  .value(); //get out of the chain

//In short:
var result = _(haystack).chain().flatten().find(function(o) { return _(o).chain().values().contains(needle).value(); }).value();
```

Of course you will have to fine-tune this and implement your $strict and whatsoever.

Comment: What does it return exactly? The path in the original array as requested, or simply the value? If it returns the value, it seems kind of unnecessary, since we are looking for a specific value.

Comment: I now see that it will return the first object with any property which value is the "needle". Is that what you meant? Because the referenced php function returns the "traversal path" of where the value was found.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to using libraries, I think Underscore.js has functionality that will get you what you're looking for, using possibly _.find(), _.pluck(), or _.pick(). There are plenty of other methods that can help with this.

- http://underscorejs.org/#find
- http://underscorejs.org/#pluck
- http://underscorejs.org/#pick

If you want to do it in core JS, have a peek under the covers of Underscore source code, which has FANTASTIC annotations / documentation:

http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html